# GLM Model checking Plots - Quasi Poisson - Poisson

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, overdispersion, quasi-likelihood

I wonder whether accounting for overdispersion in a GLM (Quasi - Poisson instead of Poisson family) has an effect on the model checking plots (plot of residuals against fitted values, a scale–location plot of residuals against fitted values, a normal QQ plot and a plot of residuals against leverages). I tested this and apart from the scale in the plots nothing changes.

Is this hazard or is this always the case?

Comment: It's always the case -- quasi Poisson is Poisson with an additional scale factor.

Comment: is the scale factor the variance (which is assumed to be a linear function of the mean for quasi-poisson)?

Comment: see the edits to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always the case -- quasi Poisson is effectively Poisson with an additional scale factor.

The dispersion parameter corresponds to rescaling a Poisson variable by that parameter.

To be more specific, the scale factor I referred above to is the dispersion parameter.

In a quasi-Poisson GLM, $E(Y)=\mu\,$, $Var(Y)=\phi.\mu$.

You can get that by taking a Poisson($\lambda$) and multiplying by $\phi$, such that $\mu=\lambda.\phi$. e.g. $Z\sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $Y=\phi.Z$; then $Y$ has the required properties for a quasi-Poisson. (To my recollection it's the only member of the natural exponential family that has the right variance function.)

For example, Clark and Thayer [1] say

> The Over-Dispersed Poisson distribution is a generalization of the Poisson, in which the
> range is a constant $\phi$ times the positive integers. That is, the variable $Y$ can take on
> values ${0,1\phi, 2\phi, 3\phi, 4\phi,...}$. It has a variance equal to $\phi$ times the mean.

People using this to model overdispersed counts don't usually worry too much about that since they look on it as a quasi-likelihood model; they're not looking on the scaled Poisson as a specific distributional choice.

---

[1]: Clark D.R. and Thayer, C.A. (2004),
A Primer on the Exponential Family of Distributions,
CAS 2004 Discussion Papers 117-148,
Casualty Actuarial Society. Arlington, Virginia

(pdf at https://www.casact.org/sites/default/files/database/dpp_dpp04_04dpp117.pdf)